# Documents queue to shared printer but won't print

Tags: windows, printing, hp

I have an HP Desk Jet 3650 printer on a Windows 7 laptop, which is shared with my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. The Ubuntu machine can see the printer and sends files to it, but the files only queue and won't print.

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to the printer using from the network like //COMPUTER-NAME/PRINTER-NAME ?

I had the same issue with print jobs not printing wirelessly to my shared printer HP K550 connected to my desktop pc running Windows 7.  I first attempted to access the printer using //COMPUTER-NAME/PRINTER-NAME .  I could see the printer but nothing would print.  I then changed the path to //xx.xx.xx.xx/PRINTER-NAME (where xx.xx.xx.xx is you IP address of the computer the printer is connected to).  Now it prints fine.

My printer Settings are below and are based on a HP K550:
Device URI: smb://192.168.1.3/HP_K550
Make and Model: HP Officejet Pro k550, hpcups 3.12.6

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Page preview
2. Select print from printer icon

After that It will be ok and you will can print again from the main Print option